# Subtracting index dates from dates in a column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this - i.e. I have an index of dates and I have a column of dates.  I simply want to subtract the index dates from the dates in the column and put that difference in another column.  However, I can seem to find how to use the index in calculations.

```
              Code   FinishDate
1990-01-01    XYZ    1999-02-14
1990-01-02    ABC    1997-01-27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but raises a warning:

```
In [168]:

df['DateDiff'] = df.FinishDate-df.index
df
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py:1851: DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe" if this is intentional.
  elif format_short and x == 0:
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py:1851: DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe" if this is intentional.
  elif format_short and x == 0:
Out[168]:
           Code FinishDate  DateDiff
1990-01-01  XYZ 1999-02-14 3331 days
1990-01-02  ABC 1997-01-27 2582 days

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

You would have to ensure your index and FinishDate are both datetimes and not strings, to do the conversion just use `pd.to_datetime()`

**EDIT**

To convert the strings to datetimes just do:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.FinishDate = pd.to_datetime(df.FinishDate)
```

I don't know if both are needed or not but this works

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for this.  I am new to Python so  just to clarify, what exactly do I type to change the column of strings to the column of dates, in this instance?  Many thanks.

Comment: @EdChum note that the deprecation warning is fixed in master/0.14 (I thought it started with numpy 1.9-dev, but apparently its in 1.8.1 as well!)

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the info I couldn't quite understand the error and was trying to see if I could cast the type to something that didn't produce an error but failed, good to know more about this

Comment: nah, just some internal oddness that <= 1.8 gave a pass on (essentially it auto-converted timedelta64[ns] -> int64 if needed), normally you need to take a view

Answer (score -3):

if you add you fields with date type like this http://prntscr.com/3f4seo

then according to my sample  query is

UPDATE `products` SET `dif_days` = DATEDIFF( `date1`, `date2` ).

hope this will help you

thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, this is in Python pandas not in an SQL database